# How to translate label of Selectbox “Sort by” for custom field in tx-news

Tags: typo3, tx-news

I have extended tx-news with a custom date-field and want to sort the list view by this field. Accordding to the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/DeveloperManual/ExtendNews/ExtendFlexforms/Index.html) I have extended the "Sort by"-Selectbox of the news-plugin an everything works fine:

`$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['news']['orderByNews'] .= ',my_field';`

`plugin.tx_news.settings.orderByAllowed := addToList(my_field)`

But how can I translate or customize the label of the option in the selectbox? Currently it shows the name of the field?

Comment: From which table do you read the properties?

Comment: I have extended the table tx_news_domain_model_news with my own field.

Comment: Do you have an override folder (TCA)?

Comment: Yes I have Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tx_news_domain_model_news.php in which I define my field.

In the backend form of the records in list module I get the Labels from there, but not in the plugin.

Comment: $GLOBALS[‘TCA’][‘tx_news_domain_model_news’][‘my_field’][‘label’] =   Try this and adjust the path to the right target

Comment: does not change anything.

Why should I do this twice? I have the following in my override:

```$tempColumns = Array(
    'my_field' => array (
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:....',
        'config' => array(....),
    ),
),
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns("tx_news_domain_model_news", $tempColumns);```
I would guess, this does the same as ```$GLOBALS[‘TCA’][‘tx_news_domain_model_news’][‘my_field’][‘label’] = ...```, or not?

Comment: My bad I didn’t  that read the question carefully. Do You want the options to be translated?

Comment: Right, translate or set a custom label name. Now I get only the field name as label.

I thouht, I would get the label from my TCA override in the plugin options too.

Comment: Can you post the options code on your question?

Comment: I did the two lines of code, which I wrote in my question. This results in the following piece of html in the backend:

    <div class="form-wizards-element">
    <select id="tceforms-select-5cd2d82b9e148426458961" name="data[tt_content] 
    [21775][pi_flexform][data][sDEF][lDEF][settings.orderBy][vDEF]" data- 
    formengine-validation-rules="[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;select&quot;,&quot;minItems&quot;:0,&quot;maxItems&quot;:99999}]" class="form-control form-control-adapt">
<option value="" data-icon=""></option>value="my_field" data-icon="">my_field</option>
</select>
</div>